# $Col(X^T A X) = Col(X^T)$ for any positive definite matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $Col(X^T A X) = Col(X^T)$ for any positive definite matrix $A$.

I have shown that the statement is true for symmetric positive definite matrix $A$. Since $A$ can be digionalized thus $A^{1/2}$ exists and is symmetric, then 
$$Col(X^T A X) = Col (X^T A^{1/2}(X^T A^{1/2})^T) = Col (X^T A^{1/2}) = Col (X^T).$$

Would this be true for non symmetric positive definite matrices?

Comment: Have you tried a numerical experiment?  To build an arbitrary non-symmetric positive definite matrix: take a random matrix $M$, a random skew-symmetric matrix $N$, and take $A = M^TM + N$.

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then $S = A + A^T$ is symmetric positive definite.  We can find an invertible $P$ so that $PSP^T = I$, which tells us that $PAP^T + PA^TP^T = I$.  So, it suffices to consider the case of $M^TM = I$.

Comment: In other words: an equivalent question is whether $Col(X^T(I + N)X) = Col(X^T)$ is true for every $X$, for every skew-symmetric $N$.

Comment: Final notes: It is equivalent to ask whether $\ker(X^TAX) = \ker(X)$; we necessarily have $\ker(X^TAX) \supset \ker(X)$. As I explain in the comments above we can, without loss of generality, take $A = I + N$ where $N^T = -N$.

That is: can $N$ and $X$ as in the problem and a vector $v$ such that $Xv \neq 0$, but $X^T(I + N)Xv = 0$?

We rewrite the equation as
$$
X^TXv  + X^TNXv = 0
$$
after that, I'm stuck too